# "Bromobenzene" vs "bromophenyl"

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the difference between the keywords Bromophenyl and Bromobenzene used in organic chemistry.[image]

Comment: Phenyl is an alkyl from benzene, the same as ethyl from ethan. I admit, more logical alkyl name of benzene would be benzyl, but it is already historically reserved for the phenyl-CH2-  alkyl. Bromo- is just a prefix for bromine substituent.

Comment: @Poutnik  do you mean we use "phenyl" when the ring joined as a alkyl group to the parent chain

Comment: Anywhere where you would use ethyl instead of ethan, you use phenyl instead of benzene. As benzene is $\ce{C6H6}$, while phynyl is $\ce{C6H5}-$. By other words, phenyl is benzene with 1 H removed, making it a single bond substituent.

Answer (score 3):

**Bromobenzene is a complete compound, bromophenyl is a description of a unit in a larger compound**

Chemists abbreviate some groups to simplify the names of more complex compounds. So while bromobenzene is a *complete* name for a compound, bromophenyl signals that the unit occurs as part of a larger compound.

In this case–to abuse strict chemical terminology a little–there is a bromobenzene unit attached to to 2 carbon on an ethanol unit and attached at the 2-carbon on the bromobenzene unit so we say *2-bromophenyl* not the more complicated "bromobenzene with the hydrogen at the two position replaced by an ethanol unit with the connection being made at the 2-position on the ethanol."